# How to prevent Picasa to scan all my disk?

Tags: picasa

On my Mac, [Picasa](http://picasaweb.google.com/) scans my whole disk to find all my pictures and videos.

I want to let Picasa scans only my Pictures directory.

How I can do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure on the Mac, but on the PC version there is a `Folder Manager` on the `Tools` menu

In that dialog you can set only the folders you want to include to `Scan Always` and everything else to `Remove From Picasa`.

[image: Folder Manager]

Comment: Yes thanks, I have it on my Mac too... :) (I had only search in Preferences Menu)